# AWS Codebuild webhook trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codebuild

I want to start codebuild if something commit ONLY to "dev" branch. But now I see, that codebuild start if something commit to all of my branch. How can I start codebuild for only "dev" branch ?

In this case I use terraform and I can show you simple codebuild webhook. As you can see, I triggered only dev branch.

```html
codebuild.tf

# CodeBuild Project
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild-plan" {
  name          = "${var.env}-codebuild-plan"
  description   = "CodeBuild project for password generator application"
  build_timeout = "5"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.codebuild-iam-role.arn

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
  }
  cache {
    type = "NO_CACHE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image = "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"  type
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"      
    privileged_mode             = true         

    environment_variable {
      name  = "EXAMPLE"
      value = var.example
    }
  }

  source {
    type            = "GITHUB"
    location        = var.github_url
    buildspec       = var.buildspec
    git_clone_depth = 1

    report_build_status = "true" # Whether to report the status of a build's start and finish to your source provider.
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role.codebuild-iam-role,
    aws_ssm_parameter.ssm-github-auth
  ]
}

resource "aws_codebuild_webhook" "webhook" {
  project_name = aws_codebuild_project.codebuild-plan.name
  build_type   = "BUILD"

  filter_group {
    filter {
      type    = "EVENT"
      pattern = "PUSH"
    }

    filter {
      type    = "HEAD_REF"
      pattern = "^refs/heads/dev"
    }
  }
}
```

In this picture you can see my test.

- Pic 1. - Config of codebuild
- Pic 2. Commit from test branch to
  repository
- Pic 3. Codebuild running

[image][image][image]

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeCommit.html?

Comment: No, because I use github as a SCM. I search info here, but dont see anything. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/github-webhook.html

Comment: Does your original pattern hold the `$` sign at the end of the pattern matching? I.e., is this line `pattern = "^refs/heads/dev"` correct or is it `pattern = "^refs/heads/dev$"`?

Comment: this pattern the same as in official documentation of github, but I try to use "^refs/heads/dev$" and "^refs/heads/dev" and result is the same. Commit to different branch = start codebuild. But i need only start build if commit to dev

Comment: Also i test function "Don`t start build under these condition" and it has the same result.

Comment: @O.Yudin Did you ever get this solved? I'm trying to understand if multiple filters in filters group are evaluated using `AND` logical operator (effectively allowing you to specify event type and branch name) or `OR` operator.

Comment: @Mati I have solved my problem and forgot to add 'solve' on this thread. The problem was on misconfiguration at AWS Console. I don't remember exactly how I fix it)) If I'm not mistake filters in filter group works with AND operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on incorrect configuration via AWS Console on AWS CodeBuild.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).